# Unexpected MySQL "foreign key constraint fails.." message

Tags: mysql

I have a three tables: **sa_Zona**, **sa_Regiune** and **sa_ZonaLista**.

```
CREATE TABLE sa_Zona (
   zona_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   regiune_fk SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 65499,
   coronim_fk SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 65499,

   nadir VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   ord_ TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
     INDEX(ord),

   delim VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '.',
   incert VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   obs VARCHAR(50)  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '',

   data_mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

   PRIMARY KEY (zona_id, coronim_fk, ord)
   )
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=latin1
COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE sa_Zona ADD FOREIGN KEY (coronim_fk) 
   REFERENCES sa_Coronim (coronim_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE sa_Zona ADD FOREIGN KEY (regiune_fk) 
   REFERENCES sa_Regiune (regiune_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;


CREATE TABLE sa_ZonaLista (
   zonalista_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   regiune_fk SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 65499,
   nume_zl VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     INDEX(nume_zl),

   data_mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

   PRIMARY KEY (zonalista_id)
   )
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8
COLLATE= utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE sa_ZonaLista ADD FOREIGN KEY (zonalista_id) 
   REFERENCES sa_Zona (zona_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE sa_ZonaLista ADD FOREIGN KEY (regiune_fk) 
   REFERENCES sa_Zona (regiune_fk)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;


CREATE TABLE sa_Regiune (
   regiune_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   nume_reg VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     INDEX(nume_reg),
   ord_ SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

   data_mod TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     INDEX(data_mod),

   PRIMARY KEY (regiune_id)
   )
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Table sa_ZonaLista and sa_Zona have the same number of rows, and with zona_id=zonalista_id and regiune_fk=regiune_fk, because sa_ZonaLista is like a VIEW of sa_Zona generated into a table for faster access time. So every time I need to delete a row from sa_Zona (which happens very rarely), I also need to delete the corresponding row from sa_ZonaLista for coherence.

When doing this, a row from sa_ZonaLista can be deleted no problem, but then, when I try to delete the corresponding row from sa_Zona, I get this unexpected message:

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`floramv`.`sa_zonalista`, CONSTRAINT `sa_zonalista_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`regiune_fk`) REFERENCES `sa_zona` (`regiune_fk`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

As far as I know, this should not happen. Any ideas why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory, **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**.

Means there is a **child record exist in some table that is bind with the record you are trying to delete** and you cannot delete any parent if it has a child record.

You have child record and so since you have put the ON DELETE RESTRICT as well as ON UPDATE RESTRICT constraints(I mean as they are default) whatever changes you make on the parent row i.e. a row in korisnici table with child rows in slike table will be restricted by MySQL.

Now for deletion you can do something like this:

Either change the **ON DELETE** constraint to CASCADE **OR**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- to disable them
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- to re-enable them
```

Comment: What is korisnici and slike ? There are no other tables subordinated to sa_Zona; however, there are other records in sa_ZonaLista which have the same regiune_fk. Deleting a record in sa_Zona would delete all records in sa_ZonaLista with that particular value of regiune_fk (if cascaded delete was enabled) ? I think this is the reason.

Comment: Actually, ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT doesn't make much sense in a production environment. The software should check that there are child rows that will be deleted when deleting a parent, but if the user decides to go ahead, they should be deleted. I am now in the stage of app development, and wanted to make sure I don't delete anything accidentally, since I still have no Administration application and I am still using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Mayank Pandeyz has popped the complete correct answer in my mind: as regiune_fk is defined now in sa_ZonaLista, when deleting a record of sa_Zona, MySQL would also delete the child records in sa_ZonaLista which have the same value of product_fk. This is not correct from the point of view of business logic, but comes from the fact that regiune_fk should have been linked to **the correct custodian** of regiune information, which is sa_Regiune with regiune_id as primary key. And, the foreign keys in sa_ZonaLista should finally be defined - in a production environment - ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE (see my last comment). Generally speaking, if a table_A has several foreign keys, any deletion in a **parent table of table_A** will prompt a deletion in table_A - if the values of the keys coincide AND ON DELETE is set to CASCADE. This might not be always self evident, although it should.